# Report Viewer: Dynamic header content by value in DataSet

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Sorry that I can't think of a good title for my question.

I am creating a `C#` report with report viewer and I am passing the report with data like below:

```
Product         Selling Date       Quantity
Pen             1-1-2015           2
Pen             1-2-2015           5
Pencil          1-1-2015           5
Pencil          1-2-2015           3
```

And I want to display **ONE** report with each "Product" showing as a header

Example:

```
Product: Pen

Selling Date          Quantity
============          ========
1-1-2015              2
1-2-2015              5

Product: Pencil

Selling Date          Quantity
============          ========
1-1-2015              5
1-2-2015              3
```

Can report viewer fulfill this requirement?
Note: I am using VS2013.

I have found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqHsrK7mfy8) for VB exactly fulfilling my requirement, but I can't find similar button "Edit detail group" in C#.

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use sub-reports to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

So I got the answer. Let's start from the very beginning.

1. In Report Viewer, insert a table.
2. Highlight the table's data row > Add Group > Parent Group
3. In the dialog popped up, select Group by "Product" in my case. A column "Product" will be added in the table
4. You can also do further grouping, say by the product's brand, by selecting the "Product" column > Add Group > Child Group > Group by "Brand"
5. Remove the auto added columns without removing the group.
6. Put your data (selling date and quantity) in the data row.
7. To add the header (Product: Pen), right click on the data row > Inside Row > Inside Group - Above
8. In the newly inserted row, put the product field in it.

Done.